# Dependency resolution for org.eclipse.uml2:types

Tags: m2eclipse

I started with a POM.xml file which worked fine with just two dependencies:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>QRE</groupId>
    <artifactId>QRE</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.ecore</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.1-v20150805-0538</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.emf.common</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0-v20150805-0538</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Now I need to add a dependency upon org.eclipse.uml.types, so I added this from [Maven Central](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.uml2/types/2.0.0-v20140602-0749):

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.uml2/types -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.uml2</groupId>
    <artifactId>types</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0-v20140602-0749</version>
</dependency>
```

I ran Maven with the "clean" and "install" goals, and got:

```
Failed to execute goal on project QRE: Could not resolve dependencies for project QRE:QRE:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.eclipse.uml2:types:jar:2.0.0-v20140602-0749 -> org.eclipse.emf:ecore:jar:[2.10.0,3.0.0): No versions available for org.eclipse.emf:ecore:jar:[2.10.0,3.0.0) within specified range -> [Help 1]
```

... which is strange because I already have a dependency on org.eclipse.emf.ecore 2.11.1-v20150805-0538, which should satisfy that dependency. I also tried changing the org.eclipse.uml2.types dependency from "jar" to "java-source" but that didn't help.

I tried ->Maven->Update Project with "Force Update of Snapshots/Releases". The result was a whole bunch of errors in the Problems tab, mostly "Missing artifact" but also "No versions available for org.eclipse.emf:ecore:jar:[2.10.0,3.0.0) within specified range" and "The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library 'C:\Users\mhl.m2\repository\org\eclipse\core\runtime\3.10.0-v20140318-2214\runtime-3.10.0-v20140318-2214.jar'   QRE".

I tried deleting the entire contents of my repository at c:\Users\mhl.m2\repository but that also didn't help.

What do I need to do to get this dependency to work?

Comment: I asked on the Eclipse EMF forum (https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/m/1738005/#msg_1738005) about this problem.  What I found out is that the Eclipse community is not maintaining their artifacts on the Maven central repository.  And that there's an underlying architectural issue about "incompatible version/persistence
policies wrt Eclipse and Maven repos". Apparently this topic is under discussion in that community.  But meanwhile, developers are left out in the cold. Which sucks.

Comment: So I developed a hack which at least gets me through a Maven compile.  I changed the Maven central pom files for org.eclipse.uml2.types and org.eclipse.uml2.common to accept a wider version range for their dependencies.  Specifically, I changed the dependency upon org.eclipse.core.runtime to accept [3.0.0,4.0.0] instead of [3.5.0,4.0.0], and upon org.eclipse.emf.ecore to accept [2.0.0,3.0.0) instead of [2.1.0,3.0.0). I think the underlying problem is that the Eclipse version number scheme is not quite compatible with the Maven one and this gets around it.

Comment: I made these changes in my local Maven repository.  That works because Maven looks there before looking at Maven central.  (We'll see whether I still have runtime dependency problems.)